# How to assign a values to a column made in a select query

Tags: mysql, sql

In a select query I can make-up columns but how can I assign values for them?

Example

```
select a.col1, a.col2, 'column3'
from A a
  union
select b.col2, b.col3, b.col3 as `column3`
from B b
```

I want to assign a default value of `-1` to the `column3` column I made in the first query. Also, I want the title of the column to still be `column3`. is this possible?

Comment: select a.col1,a.col2,'-1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select a.col1, a.col2, -1 as column3
from A a
  union
select b.col2, b.col3, b.col3
from B b
```

Or this if b.col3 is varchar

```
select a.col1, a.col2, '-1' column3
from A a
  union
select b.col2, b.col3, b.col3
from B b
```

If A and B table has the same values for the tree columns the database will do an DISTINCT to avoid that, if you want, use UNION ALL

Comment: doing this, `-1`, also becomes the column title. This is not the desired effect i was hoping for. I still want the column name to be, say `column3`, but have default value of `-1`.

Comment: Edited my answer according your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
To create a dummy column and assgin values to it we can use

select a.col1, a.col2, '-1' as col3 from A a
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most of the way there:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, -1 as 'column3'
from A a
  union
select b.col2, b.col3, b.col3
from B b
```